# Bootstrap menu and openlayers

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, menu, twitter-bootstrap, openlayers

i use bootstrap twitter 2 in my page.

I have a dropdown menu that works without problems except when i load the openlayers.js file.

When i navigate to other pages it works, but when i got access in the page where i load the openlayer.js file it crashes (the style is ok but the dropdown functionality is not working)

I believe that is an openlayers conflict because if i don't load this js file then the menu works without problems.

How can i solce this conflict ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: give us some code please.
Go to the page with openlayers in it, and check (ctrl+U) if the js from bootstrap menu is being loaded

Comment: I am having the same issue - the bootstrap js is loading and this problem only occurs on pages which load openlayers, so the conflict is between openlayers and bootstrap.... Is there any way to "isolate" one from the other to prevent the conflict?